# Always getting intent chooser resultcode as RESULT_CANCELLED and data as null

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file

I'm new in Android Programming and this my very first app. I'm getting a problem with intents. File chooser is returning **data** value as **null** and also **resultCode** as **-1**. Though I'm getting requestCode as given.

I have tried couple of solutions as followed:

> [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512264/fragments-startactivityforresult-always-return-resultcode-0-and-intent-null-on-c)
>   [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898053/android-getting-result-canceled-when-i-specifically-add-result-ok)

I'm trying to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619325/android-directory-and-file-chooser-android-library) code.

#### **EDIT**

My code so far is: [here](http://pastebin.com/y8zT4VHz)

Comment: is it only in some devices  ?

Comment: Can you show us your code of the activity that gets called for the result?

Comment: [That code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619325/android-directory-and-file-chooser-android-library) is terrible. `file/*` is not a valid wildcard MIME type, and the `getRealPathFromURI()` is completely wrong. Do not use that code.

Comment: thnx for replying,
@Nithinlal : I have tried on Genymotion 4.4.2 custom device and Redmi Note 4g. It doesn't work on any of them.
@reVerse : There is no any other activity there. File choose dialog pops up and lets user to to select a file
@CommonsWare : 1. I have changed `file/*` with `image/*` as in [mycode](http://pastebin.com/y8zT4VHz) and also getRealPathFromURI() seems to be working fine as Android Studio is not giving any error.